# Let $A= \{(x,y) \mid xy=0\}$ and $B=\{(x,y)\mid xy=1\}.$ Show that $A$ and $B$ are closed and that $d(A,B) =0$.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

> Let $A= \{(x,y) \mid xy=0\}$ and $B=\{(x,y)\mid xy=1\}.$ Show that $A$ and $B$ are closed and that $d(A,B) =0$.

For the first part we have that $A=\{(x,y) \mid f(z)=0\} = f^{-1}(\{0\})$, where $f(z) = \operatorname{pr_1}(z)\operatorname{pr_2}(z)$ and thus the closed preimage of a continuous function implies that the set is closed. Similarly for $B = \{(x,y) \mid f(z)=1\} = f^{-1}(\{1\})$, where $f(z) = \operatorname{pr_1}(z)\operatorname{pr_2}(z)$. Here singletons are closed since were dealing with the usual metric presumably. For $$d(A,B) = \inf \{d(x,y) \mid x \in A, y \in B \}$$ I'm not sure how to show that this is $0$. Plotting the graphs it's quite clear since $xy=1 \iff y = \frac1x$ which tends to $0$ as $x \to \infty$ and $xy=0$ is just the $x$-axis, but how can I show this?

Comment: $xy=0$ is not just the $x$-axis, but the the $x$-axis and the $y$-axis together. That is $$A=\{(0,y)|y\in\mathbb R\}\cup\{(x,0)|x\in\mathbb R\}$$

Comment: My mistake. It's however closed still under the preimage definition?

Comment: yes, the "prove $A,B$ are closed" part is correct. My suggestion to prove that $d(A,B)=0$ is to construct a sequence of points $x_n\in A$ and a sequence $y_n\in B$ such that $d(x_n,y_n)\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Hint, consider a sequence $a_n\in\mathbb R$ of non zero real numbers and use $x_n=(a_n,0)$ and $y_n=(a_n,\frac{1}{a_n})$. Can you think of an appropriate sequence $a_n$?

Answer (score 1):

$p: (x,y) \to xy$ is continuous and $A=p^{-1}[\{0\}]$ and $B = p^{-1}[\{1\}]$ are thus closed.

$d_2((x,0), (x,\frac1x))=\frac1x$ for all $x >0$ and so for any $r>0$ there are points $a\in A, b \in B$ so that $d_2(a,b)< r$. This shows $d(A,B)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

For each $x>0$, $(x,0)\in A$, $\left(x,\frac1x\right)\in B$ and $d\left((x,0),\left(x,\frac1x\right)\right)=\frac1x$. Since $\frac1x$ can be arbitrarily small, $d(A,B)=0$.